# Check to see if ID is contained in a txt file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to download new tweets from a particular user and filter with a few other rules. How do I cross reference the tweet ID from the tweet I am handling with what ID's are in the tweetid.txt file to avoid duplicating what I am saving in the NRE_tweet file?

This is what I have written so far that is producing duplicates.

```
i = 0
for tweet in NRE_tweets:

    tweet_ids = open('tweetid.txt', 'a+')

    if NRE_tweets[i]['in_reply_to_screen_name'] is None:

        if NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'] not in tweet_ids.readlines():
            print("adding tweet " + str(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str']))
            info_wanted.append(NRE_tweets[i]['text'])
            info_wanted.append(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'])
            info_wanted.append(NRE_tweets[i]['created_at'])

            NRE_file = open('NRE.txt', 'a')
            NRE_file.write(str(info_wanted) + '\n')
            NRE_file.close()

            append_tweet_ids = open('tweetid.txt', 'a')
            append_tweet_ids.write(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'] + '\n')
            append_tweet_ids.close()

    tweet_ids.close()
    info_wanted = []

    i += 1
```

EDIT: Thanks for advice, working code is now sorted. There is a few things I can do to make it cleaner, but for now... It works.

```
NRE_tweets = t.statuses.user_timeline(screen_name='NRE_northern')
i = 0

NRE_file = open('NRE.txt', 'a')
openFile = shelve.open('tweetid')

try:
    loadIDs = openFile['list_id']
    print("list_id's loaded")
except:
    print("exception entered")
    loadIDs = []

for tweet in NRE_tweets:
    if NRE_tweets[i]['in_reply_to_screen_name'] is None: # check that tweet isn't a reply
        if NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'] in loadIDs:
            print(str(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str']) + ' already stored')

        else:
            print("adding " + str(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str']))
            # added wanted elements to a list
            info_wanted.append(NRE_tweets[i]['text'])
            info_wanted.append(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'])
            info_wanted.append(NRE_tweets[i]['created_at'])

            # added list to txt file
            NRE_file.write(str(info_wanted) + '\n')

            loadIDs.append(NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'])
            openFile['list_id'] = loadIDs

    info_wanted = []

    i += 1

print(openFile['list_id'])  
NRE_file.close()
openFile.close()
```

Comment: Don't keep opening the files, open them outside the loop once, if you don't want dupes you are going to have to load the data from the file. I think a file is probably the wrong structure to be using though, you probably want at least to dump a dict or maybe something like a sqlite db

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `if x is None:` in your code, unless there's a chance that `x` is literally `None`. Because only `None is None` and everybody else (0, empty iterables, etc) are fakers :) Instead, you should use `if not x`.

`readlines()` returns the lines in the file, including the line ending `\n` for each line. So you should write `if (NRE_tweets[i]['id_str'] + '\n') not in tweet_ids.readlines():`

Like you've been advised in a comment, open the file once *before* your for loop and close *after* the for loop. Also consider using the `shelve` module (or `sqlite3`) for this; it'll make handling the data a lot easier.

EDIT:

Also I notice you opened `tweetid.txt` twice without closing in between. Theres no need for the second `open()` inside the IF block. You can simply call `write()` using the first file handle, in order to add the new ID to the file. You should also call `readlines()` outside the loop and save it to a list which you then use in the for loop header, because, with your new code structure, subsequent calls to `readlines()` will return an empty string as the file has been exhausted. So when you find a new ID, you append it to this list, as well as call `write()` to add the ID to `tweetid.txt`.

An alternative is that you open the file in read mode at first, call `readlines()` and save the result to a list, close the file. Start the loop and perform all your operations on the list; add new IDs, delete, whatever. At the end of the loop, you re-open `tweetid.txt` in write mode and write the lists contents to the file; it will overwrite the old contents. Use this method if you could be adding a lot of new IDs.

Structure your code so that you only open files once, operate on them and finally close them.

Comment: When the data is downloaded from twitter, if the tweet is a reply to someone in the key: 'In_reply_to_screen_name' it either returns a string of the person who it's a reply to. Or a None value if the post is not a reply. I only want these tweets with the None value.

I have re-written the code to include shelves. I can't test it until I get to my home PC because I can't get the modules onto my work computer. But I've done some testing in IDLE. Concepts seem to work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks to some of the help. Some way to go in what I am aiming to do. But I have a working code that at least gets the data that I want.

edited to add working code.

Comment: @Levo Nice! A few things though: `openFile['list_id'] = loadIDs` can be placed after the loop, to make changes once and for all. Also since you know that `info_wanted` will always have only 3 items, you could pre-allocate space before the loop with `info_wanted = [""]*3` and then in the loop, you overwrite the items at those positions, instead of calling `append()` which is more costly in the long run. These are minor optimizations though, only necessary if you'll be handling a lot of data. Also since tweetid.txt is only a list of IDs, the `pickle` module may be more suitable. Cheers :)